# R base graphics: overlapping axis tick labels from different plots with layout

Tags: r

I'm making stacked boxplots and plots on top of one another using R's `layout` command in base graphics.
The graphs look great, except that y-axis labels from different plots overlap (highlighted in red circle):

[image: overlapping axis labels]

Similar questions are here online, but none of them use `layout`.

I don't want to expand the space between the plots, I don't think this will look good.

How 
I've tried reducing the font size, but the labels still go outside the plot area.
How can I set R's boxplot and plot so that the tick labels do not go above or below the red line, i.e. the max/min y-value, in the image above?

Some example code

```
legend_space <- -0.26
right <- 10.5
bottom <- 0
left <- 5
top <- 0
cex_main = 1
setEPS()
postscript('figure.eps')
g1 <- c()
g2 <- c()
p <- c()
percent <- c()
sum_p <- c()
sum_percent <- c()
g1_means <- c()
g2_means <- c()
xaxis <- c()
sum_p[1] <- 0.0430904
xaxis[1] <- 2984116
p[1] <- 0.0430904
percent[1] <- -65.1758
sum_percent[1] <- -65.1758
g1[1] <- list(c(47.058824,100.000000,100.000000))
g1_means[1] <- 84.482759
g2[1] <- list(c(13.750000,4.123711,96.000000))
g2_means[1] <- 19.306931
sum_p[2] <- 0.0443229
xaxis[2] <- 2984148
p[2] <- 0.0587825
percent[2] <- -73.8956
sum_percent[2] <- -69.332
g1[2] <- list(c(94.285714,94.736842,100.000000))
g1_means[2] <- 95.145631
g2[2] <- list(c(10.588235,0.000000,92.592593))
g2_means[2] <- 21.250000
sum_p[3] <- 0.0444647
xaxis[3] <- 2984157
p[3] <- 0.124606
percent[3] <- -40.2577
sum_percent[3] <- -60.3056
g1[3] <- list(c(76.315789,94.736842,64.705882))
g1_means[3] <- 83.928571
g2[3] <- list(c(63.529412,0.000000,60.000000))
g2_means[3] <- 43.670886
sum_p[4] <- 0.0393696
xaxis[4] <- 2984168
p[4] <- 0.0310268
percent[4] <- -38.4133
sum_percent[4] <- -54.7893
g1[4] <- list(c(59.459459,57.894737,100.000000))
g1_means[4] <- 64.864865
g2[4] <- list(c(35.294118,6.250000,36.363636))
g2_means[4] <- 26.451613
sum_p[5] <- 0.0304293
xaxis[5] <- 2984175
p[5] <- 0.0344261
percent[5] <- -50.5157
sum_percent[5] <- -54.0582
g1[5] <- list(c(62.500000,94.736842,100.000000))
g1_means[5] <- 85.849057
g2[5] <- list(c(52.873563,6.250000,26.666667))
g2_means[5] <- 35.333333
layout(matrix(c(0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4), nrow = 5, byrow = TRUE), heights = c(0.2,1,1,1,1.4))
par(mar = c(bottom, left, top, right))
boxplot(g1, xaxt = 'n', range = 0, ylab = '%', ylim = c(0,100), col = 'white', cex.lab=1.5, cex.axis=cex_main, cex.main=cex_main, cex.sub=1.5, xlim = c(0.5,length(g1)+0.5))
title('title', outer = TRUE, line = -1.5)
lines(g1_means, col='dark green', lwd = 3)
par(xpd=TRUE)
legend('topright',inset = c(legend_space,0), c('Control', 'Weighted Mean'), col = c('black','dark green'), lwd = c(1,3))
boxplot(g2, xaxt = 'n', range = 0, main = NULL, ylim = c(0,100), ylab = '%', col = 'gray',  cex.lab=1.5, cex.axis=cex_main, cex.main=cex_main, cex.sub=1.5, xlim = c(0.5,length(g2)+0.5))
lines(g2_means, col='dark green', lwd = 3)
par(xpd=TRUE)
legend('topright',inset = c(legend_space,0),c('Case', 'Weighted Mean'), col = c('black','dark green'), lwd = c(1,3))
par(mar = c(bottom, left, top, right))#'mar’ A numerical vector of the form 'c(bottom, left, top, right)’
plot(p, xaxt='n', ylab = 'P', type = 'l', lty = 1, lwd = 3, cex.lab=1.5, cex.axis=1, cex.main=cex_main, cex.sub=1.5, , log = 'y', xlim = c(0.5,length(p)+0.5), ylim = c(min(p,sum_p), max(p, sum_p)))
points(sum_p, xaxt='n', ylab = 'P', type = 'l', col = 'blue', lty = 2, lwd = 3)
legend('topright', inset=c(legend_space,0), c('CpG P', 'Moving P Mean'), col = c('black','blue'), lwd=c(3,3), lty=c(1,2))
par(mar = c(bottom+5, left, top, right))#'mar’ A numerical vector of the form 'c(bottom, left, top, right)’
plot(percent, xaxt='n', ylab = '% Diff.', xlab = 'CpG', type = 'l', lty = 1, lwd = 3, cex.lab=1.5, cex.axis=1, cex.main=cex_main, cex.sub=1.5, xlim = c(0.5,length(percent)+0.5), ylim = c(min(percent, sum_percent), max(percent, sum_percent)))
points(sum_percent, xaxt='n', xlab = 'CpG', type = 'l', col = 'blue', lty = 2, lwd = 3)
par(xpd=TRUE)
legend('topright', inset=c(legend_space,0), c('Percent', 'Moving Mean %'), col = c('black','blue'), lwd=c(3,3), lty=c(1,2))
axis( 1, at=1:length(xaxis), xaxis)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducable example?

Comment: @count I've added a sample of code to produce the 5-plot layout stack

Comment: Try `las=2` in the `par` Settings.

Comment: @count thanks! that worked!

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @count, the solution is simply to use

`las=2` in `par` settings.  `las=2` sets the labels to be read vertically.